# how to create private chat between two users with socket.io and sailsjs?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, sails.js

I create something like chat, I know how to send messages to all users in room with(sails.sockets.broadcast(...e.m)) but can't understand how to send message to one user(I think chat between 2 users), when second user send message to the first user, first get the sent by second, but when I create 3 users, and when the third user send message to first - the second user too get that message, how can I avoid this. Who knows how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603672/sailsjs-socket-io

Comment: Hi Lonely Planet, I need an example of personal chat between two users. Above example suits  for one to many chat

Comment: You just can have a channel per two users